# How to change the screen to landscape in android

Tags: android-layout

I have set these in the android manifest.xml file:

`activity android:name=".HelloActivity"`

android:label="@string/app_name"

android:configChanges="orientation"

android:screenOrientation="landscape">

But when running in the emulator i got the screen as shown here. What would be the problem.Why i am not getting horizontally[image]

I want to view like this: i have seen this in a book, but he didnt explained how to get this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `CTRL-F12` found [here](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/changing-android-emulators-orientation/). Honestly the android emulator sucks, and if ur doing any real development, u should get a real phone